# jQuery hide image without $somestuff in title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to code a piece where thousands of image thumbnails are on a page and the users want to search for them rapidly and repetatively.

So turned to trusty jQuery. I have come up with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="search"]').keyup(function(e){
        console.log('checking...');
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.val().length > 3 || e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
           var check = 'img[title*="' + $this.val() + '"]';

           $.each($('.asset'), function() {
               $(this).show();
               $(this).not(check).hide();
           })

            console.log(check);
        } else {
            console.log('False');
        };
    });
});
```

Which only partially works. The bit it fails on is that `$(this).not(check).hide();` simply hides everything without selecting only the images with the search query in their title.

Is there a way to get jQuery to complete this task?

Comment: We need an example of the HTML to give the exact solution. Are your images inside `.asset` ? Do they have the `asset` class ?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Don't keep repeating `$('input[name="search"])`, that's an expensive selector -- use `$(this)` inside the handler function (even better, assign it to a variable with `$this = $(this);`).

Comment: @Huangism When editing someone else's question, you should not make structural changes to the code. Just reformat it if necessary, but adding variables is not appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name="search"]').keyup(function(e){
    console.log('checking...');

    var search = $(this).val();
    if(search.length > 3 || e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
       $(".asset img").hide();
       $(".asset img[title*='" + search + "']").show();
    } else {
       console.log('False');
    };
});
```

The problem with your selector is that `$(this).not(check)` checks whether `$(this)` matches the `check` selector, but I'm guessing that `.asset` are the DIVs containing the IMGs, not the image elements themselves.

Comment: can't be sure about the asset and image html structure since there is no code, but this is a cleaner/faster logic

Comment: The symptom strongly suggests that this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks this works well, you are right in assuming that the html was <div class="asset"><img ... The only thing I need to adapt that the images parant div should be hidden/shown rather than just the image, but that is simple enough. Thanks all!